# Get array element in observable at particular index [Typescript]

Tags: angular, observable, angularfire2

I am running an ionic3 app with Angular4 and angularfire2-Firestore.

How does one go about getting a single object from an Observable. I am looking to return in typescript.

```
console.log(this.opportunity.title)  //   "Title1"
```

In the code below I am using the getOpportunityByIndex() method with index as the parameter. I am getting the following output and I'm not sure what to do next.

```
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
    operator:MapOperator {thisArg: undefined, project: ƒ}
    source:Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
    _isScalar:false
    __proto__:Object
```

Code

```
export interface Opportunity { title: string;  }
export interface OpportunityId extends Opportunity { id: string; }

opportunities: Observable<OpportunityId[]>;

  constructor( public firebaseProvider: FirebaseProvider)   {
    this.opportunities = this.firebaseProvider.getOpportunities();
  }

  getOpportunityByIndex(index: number) {            
     this.opportunity = this.opportunities.map(arr => arr[index]);
     console.log(this.opportunity.title);
    }
}
```

FirebaseProviderService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

export interface Opportunity { title: string;  }
export interface OpportunityId extends Opportunity { id?: string; }

@Injectable()
  export class FirebaseProvider {    
  private opportunitiesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<OpportunityId>;
  opportunity: Opportunity

  constructor(afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.opportunitiesCollection = afs.collection<Opportunity>('opportunities');
    this.opportunities = this.opportunitiesCollection.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Opportunity;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      });
    });
  }

   getOpportunities() {
    return this.opportunities;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand of your example `this.opportunities` is returning an observable with the array of opportunities. Having this you just need to subscribe to the stream and then you can pick the specific index passed by parameter. This is what you need to do:

```
getOpportunityByIndex(index: number) {            
 this.opportunities
 .subscribe( opportunities => {
     this.opportunity = opportunities[index];
     console.log(this.opportunity.title);
  });

}
```

**Edit**

If you want to make it a bit more flexible you can make the list of opportunities a regular array

```
opportunities: OpportunityId[]
```

and then in the constructor you do

```
constructor( public firebaseProvider:FirebaseProvider)   {
    this.firebaseProvider.getOpportunities()
    .subscribe( opportunities => {
        this.opportunities = opportunities;
    });
```

}

Then you can simply do whenever you want to call it

```
getOpportunityByIndex(index: number) {            
   this.opportunity = this.opportunities[index];
   console.log(this.opportunity.title);
}
```

Comment: You are correct, this method seems to run great in the constructor, however I cannot return the opportunity.title if I run the method anytime after the app is loaded such as a click event.

Comment: I’ve edited my answer to be a bit more flexible and consider your case scenario.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks so much Hugo Noro

Comment: Always glad to help :)