# Retrieve single value from Firebase Real Time Database (Angularfire 5 and Ionic 3)

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2

I want to be able to use a single value from of an Real Time Database (RTD) entry. With Firestore I was able to use the following code:

```
interface Led{
  currentState: boolean,
  lightSensor: number
}

currentState: boolean;
lightSensor: number;

this.afs.collection('Led').valueChanges().subscribe((Led: any) => {
  this.lightSensor = Led[0].lightSensor;
  this.currentState = Led[0].currentState;
})
```

I was then able to call currentState or lightSensor in to HTML and display the values. All the examples I can find for RTD use ngFor and display JSON data, i have no idea how to get the single value out of this data. I have tried the following which is essentially copied from my Firestore code:

```
this.db.list('leafBox001').valueChanges().subscribe((Led: any) => {
  this.currentState = Led[0].currentState;
  console.log(this.currentState);
});
```

Console log returns undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is simply my lack of familiarity with the language. Here is the answer I was looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/47877360/9971934

Answer (score 3):

You can just get the object by it't key:

```
this.db.object(`leafBox001/${id}`).valueChanges()
```

Comment: I'm so clueless I don't know how to get the value from the object... The answer I found sorts it out for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Follow a METHOD example:

```
getCategory(idCategoria:string) {
  this.refCategoria = this.db.list('categorias',

  ref => ref.orderByChild('id').equalTo(idCategoria));

  this.refCategoria.valueChanges().subscribe(

    (datas) => { console.log("datas", datas) }
  );
```

}

This is the filter:

```
ref.orderByChild('id').equalTo(idCategoria))
```

'id' => field of my collection used to index the data.
'idCategoria' => this is a "id" of a registry in my RTDB.